# Copying a file to another Project's Debug folder in the Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio, build, prism, modularity, post-build-event

This is driving me insane. With [Prism's Modularity Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068%28PandP.40%29.aspx), building a Module moves it to the main application's `bin\Debug` folder. When I try to do the same, the file goes to the application's `bin\Release` folder. What am I doing wrong??

Post-Build Event

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)MyModule.dll" 
      "$(SolutionDir)MainApplication\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Modules\" /Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $(ConfigurationName) tag will contain the name of the current Solution Configuration.

You can change the solution configuration you are building under by going to **Build** -> **Configuration Manager** and change the **Active Solution Configuration** to "Debug". Alternatively there is a dropdown at the top of Visual Studio with this as well.